# Which instrument for arbitrary signal commutation (matrix)

Tags: interface, remote-control, testing, instrumentation, test-equipment

I would like to test a bunch of sensors. Each sensor has a DB15 connector with mixed digital and analog signals (bw ~5MHz, Z ~120R).

I am looking for an instrument where I can control which couple of sensors I would like to interconnect to the measurement PC. I've seen commutation switch such as the Keithley 3706A, but these guys does not accept custom commutation board when I can populate my own connectors and my own relays.

So I am thinking to make my own commutation system with a MCU, a FTDI and a bunch of analog switch and relays.

I feel this is a very common need in the testing area and I would like to know what commercial solution can be used in my case.

Comment: Are you asking for purchasing recommendations? If you are the question will be closed as being off-topic for EE.

Comment: No I am not since I propose also to make my own electronic. I just don't want to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get away with analogue switches you should but, if you can't I've designed pretty much what you might need and used pickering reed relays (type 107): -

[image]

Who cares about reinventing the wheel - wheels work so use 'em.

You can stack'em up close - I had about 96 differential input channels that needed testing on a pice of equipment - we used the relays for sequencing thru and injecting signals. They are good for very low level signals (wetting current problems etc..). And, they do a changeover version I've used on a later bit of equipment.

They also (and here's the purchasing recommendation!) do modules that are addressable.